# Cannot load Entity Framework assembly in Azure website - The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, azure

I have an MVC4 web application running locally using Entity Framework 6. It is running as any CPU. When I deploy to Azure via web deploy the home page loads fine, but when I browse to a page that uses Entity Framework I see:

> Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.

I have tried building / deploying as X64 and x86. I have tried changing the platform mode between 32 and 64 bit in the Azure configure tab. I have tried Integrated and Classic modes. I have tried removing the package and reinstalling via NuGet.

Additionally if I try to run locally as X64 then it gives:

> Could not load file or assembly 'ProjectName' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

This means it fails on the first page, before even getting to the page that uses Entity Framework.

How do I fix being able to use Entity Framework on Azure websites?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. Using FTP I noticed some unneeded DLLs in my bin folder, so I deleted all the DLLs and republished. That fixed it!